# Teamviewer to a computer that is Teamviewered to you

Tags: teamviewer, infinite-loop

What happens when I Teamviewer to a computer that is Teamviewered back to me? Will it create an Infinite loop?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes. Then it lags. Then it crashes. Congratulations, you just tore a hole in the space-time continuum. Are you happy now?!

Comment: Teamviewered?  I like it.

Comment: probably.. VNC does, it's amusing. windows open up within other windows. And it doesn't even crash I don't think, I think the computer runs out of RAM with VNC.. So you have to have a cmd prompt open and do taskkill /f /im vncviewer.exe  or something like that and it goes through all processes terminating them very fast, faster than they open.. Or you could try to manually close them faster than they're opening. If you succeed in closing the windows faster than they open, then you can save the day too. that's with VNC. Teamviewer may have similarities.

Comment: @Bob fortunately a computer technician can repair the hole in the space-time continuum, and make it shrink and disappear rather than grow almost exponentially!

Comment: @Keltari I avoided using it for a while after somebody thought I was installing  something called "Teen Viewer". But fortunately they never again asked me to fix their computer and what with their naked little children running around me, it's a lucky get away ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This example assumes your example `when I Teamviewer to a computer that is Teamviewered back to me?`.

Assuming you "Teamviewer" their computer, the view should be a recursive tunnel of your desktop, somewhat similar to this:

[image: first image I could find on Google Images]

As Kevin Panko mentioned, the effect is similar to a mirror facing another mirror.

Comment: If you use a screen magnifier and look closely, Bill Gates is slowly falling down the tunnel! :P

Comment: I have tested this with the latest version of TW and your statement is correct, an infinite tunnel loop is created.

Answer (score 2):

The effect would be similar to when you view a mirror facing another mirror.  It forms a loop, and the image on one screen appears on the other screen after a short time, which then causes a new image to appear on the first, and so on.